# Como manipulo a ordem dos arquivos em uma ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Estou desenvolvendo um programa, na qual parte dos processos requer que eu pegue a numeração do último arquivo listado dentro de uma `ArrayList`.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, quando minha `ArrayList` começa a adicionar os arquivos listados no diretório ele adiciona os arquivos de forma correta na sequência de itens dentro da array, mas quando ele chega no arquivo de número 9 a array substitui o primeiro arquivo da sequência pelo 10, e só reconhece o número 1 do completo 10. Como faço para a array reconhecer o 10 como número que vem depois do 9?

Comment: provavelmente está tratando essa número como uma String, e 1 vem antes do 9.

Comment: @neto Adicione o código que vc já desenvolveu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Ideia da solução

Primeiro, você tem que ver que os nomes dos arquivos tem o formato *prefixo + sufixo*, onde o sufixo é um número. Com isso, podemos orgazinar os seus arquivos, ordenando-os primeiramente pelo prefixo e depois pelo sufixo.

## Implementação da solução

Assim sendo, você vai precisar de uma função que saiba ordenar os nomes dos arquivos corretamente. Aqui vai uma:

```
public static int comparaNomesDeArquivos(String nome1, String nome2) {
    if (Objects.equals(nome1, nome2)) return 0;
    if (nome1 == null) return -1;
    if (nome2 == null) return 1;

    int sufixo1 = 0, sufixo2 = 0;
    int n;
    int p = 1;
    for (n = nome1.length() - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
        char c = nome1.charAt(n);
        if (c < '0' || c > '9') break;
        sufixo1 += (c - '0') * p;
        p *= 10;
    }
    p = 1;
    String prefixo1 = nome1.substring(0, n + 1);
    for (n = nome2.length() - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
        char c = nome2.charAt(n);
        if (c < '0' || c > '9') break;
        sufixo2 += (c - '0') * p;
        p *= 10;
    }
    String prefixo2 = nome2.substring(0, n + 1);
    int a = prefixo1.compareTo(prefixo2);
    if (a != 0) return a;
    int b = sufixo1 - sufixo2;
    if (b != 0) return b;
    return nome1.compareTo(nome2);
}
```

A explicação dessa função é a seguinte:

1. Como qualquer [função de comparação em Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), ela tem como parâmetro dois elementos a serem comparados. Retorna um número positivo se o primeiro elemento for depois do segundo, negativo se for antes, ou zero se os dois forem iguais.
2. Por uma questão de otimização, verifica-se inicialmente se as `String`s são idênticas, e neste caso sabe-se que são iguais. Este caso é determinado com o [`Objects.equals(Object, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-). Essa verificação funciona também se ambas as `String`s forem `null`.
3. Caso uma das `String`s seja `null` (e já se sabe que apenas uma delas poderia ser porque o caso onde as duas são é tratado no passo 2), então considera que `null` antecede qualquer outra coisa, retornando -1 ou 1 nestes casos.
4. Para separar o prefixo do sufixo, essa função percorre cada string de trás-para-frente com a finalidade de determiná-los Para isso é usado um laço `for` para cada.
5. Se o prefixo das `String`s for diferente, então a ordenação é dada pelo prefixo.
6. Sendo os prefixos iguais, então a ordenação é dada pelo sufixo, que é um número.
7. Sendo os prefixos e sufixos iguais, o que pode acontecer se você comparar `batatinha123` com `batatinha0123`, ou seja, quando a diferença se dá apenas pelos zeros a esquerda do número, então ele usa a forma de comparação padrão.

Sabendo comparar-se as `String`s, você pode montar uma função para comparar arquivos. Eu não sei exatamente como é que você está repressentando um arquivo. Se for diretamente pelos seus nomes, então você pode ignorar essa parte. Caso contrário, supondo que o método `getFilename()` seja o que determine o nome do arquivo, faça isso:

```
public static int comparaArquivosPorNome(Arquivo arquivo1, Arquivo arquivo2) {
    String nome1 = arquivo1 == null ? null : arquivo1.getFilename();
    String nome2 = arquivo2 == null ? null : arquivo2.getFilename();
    return comparaNomesDeArquivos(nome1, nome2);
}
```

Ah, e vamos supor que os métodos acima estão em uma classe chamada de `Ordenacao`.

Por fim, você pode ordenar a sua `List<Arquivo>` usando [o método `sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-):

```
Collections.sort(suaArrayList, Ordenacao::comparaArquivosPorNome);
```

Se você estiver usando apenas uma `List<String>` ao invés de `List<Arquivo>`, use isso:

```
Collections.sort(suaArrayList, Ordenacao::comparaNomesDeArquivos);
```

## Teste

Para testar tudo isso, vamos supor que esta seja a classe `Arquivo`:

```
public class Arquivo {
    private String nome;

    public Arquivo(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return nome;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "arquivo {" + nome + "}";
    }
}
```

E que esta seja a classe que faz os nossos testes:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 1. Cria as listas.
        List<String> lista1 = Arrays.asList(
            "batata", "batata0", "batata000", "batata3", null, "azul 6", "azul 50", "azul 51", "batata", "azul 051", "azul 5", "laranja"
        );
        List<Arquivo> lista2 = lista1.stream().map(Arquivo::new).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // 2. Ordena as listas.
        Collections.sort(lista1, Ordenacao::comparaNomesDeArquivos);
        Collections.sort(lista2, Ordenacao::comparaArquivosPorNome);

        // 3. Mostra as listas ordenadas.
        System.out.println(lista1);
        System.out.println(lista2);
    }
}
```

Eis a saída produzida:

```
[null, azul 5, azul 6, azul 50, azul 051, azul 51, batata, batata, batata0, batata000, batata3, laranja]                                                                                                      
[arquivo {null}, arquivo {azul 5}, arquivo {azul 6}, arquivo {azul 50}, arquivo {azul 051}, arquivo {azul 51}, arquivo {batata}, arquivo {batata}, arquivo {batata0}, arquivo {batata000}, arquivo {batata3}, arquivo {laranja}]
```

[Veja tudo isso funcionando no site tutorialspoint.](https://goo.gl/3ejeXb) (Faça o teste ao clicar no botão compilar e depois no botão executar.)

Answer (score 0):

Certa vez eu tive que ordenar minha lista pela data, e o sqlite não tratava como data, o que eu fiz:

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Call another) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        java.util.Date dateComparer, dateActual;

        try {
            dateActual = sdf.parse(this.getData());
            dateComparer = sdf.parse(another.getData());

            if (dateActual.before(dateComparer)) {
                return Constants.SUCESS;
            }
            if (dateActual.after(dateComparer)) {
                return Constants.ERROR;
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Depois eu ordernei minha lista na chamada:

```
Collections.sort(calls)
```

Então eu acho que você teria só que converter o `String` para inteiro e comparar.

Comment: O problema é que eu não tenho apenas números, tenho palavras que vem antes da numeração, que é o nome do arquivo, tentei retirar as palavras com o replaceAll, e jogar em um tipo inteiro fazendo uma conversão, mas ele continua dando erro de formato inapropriado...